# Item list fetched with useEffect hook renders only after it is filtered with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My problem is that I am trying to show data (item list) on the first render using useEffect, with useState hooks, and after it is rendered I want to filter these mapped items.

At the moment when I get to items page, I get zero items rendered on-page. And they are rendered only after I filter them (either by search filter or by choosing the desired color from the select dropdown).

Below I show my code:

```
...
  var [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<any>("");
  var [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<any>([]);
  const handleInput = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };
  var [pickedColor, setPickedColor] = useState<any>("");
  var [colorPickResults, setColorPickResults] = useState<any>([]);
  const handleColorChange = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setPickedColor(e.target.value);
  };
  var [items, setItems] = useState<any>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    var message: string = "";
    var fetchItems = () => {
      axios
        .get("/api/products")
        .then((res: any) => {
          console.log("res :", res);
          setItems(res.data.data[0].products);
          console.log("res.data.data[0].products :", res.data.data[0].products);
          if (res.status === 200) {
            message = "Products successfuly fetched.";
            console.log(message);
          } else {
            message = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            console.log(message);
          }
        })
        .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
    };
    fetchItems();
    const resultsFromSearch = items.filter((item: any) =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    setSearchResults(resultsFromSearch);
    const resultsFromPickedColor = resultsFromSearch.filter((item: any) =>
      item.color.toLowerCase().includes(pickedColor)
    );
    setColorPickResults(resultsFromPickedColor);
  }, [searchTerm, pickedColor]);
  var filteredItems = colorPickResults;
  var itemList = filteredItems.map((item: any) => {
    return (
      <div key={item.id} style={{ width: "370px", padding: "1rem" }}>
...
```

I get successful message in the console, and item is successfully fetched as I mentioned above.

What I have tried:
1.Adding "items" to: [searchTerm, pickedColor, items] array, but then useEffect creates infinite loop when fetching items, and (probably) re-renders component at each fetch.

What can I change to get desired functionality mentioned at start of my post?
Should I add some other hooks like useContext,useMemo? Or maybe I can somehow separate fetching from filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling async function and trying access data it will return somewhere later will never work as you expect

```
fetchItems();
const resultsFromSearch = items.filter((item: any) =>
  item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
);
```

You should either add that code to `.then` inside `fetchItems` or probably have separate `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
const resultsFromSearch = items.filter((item: any) =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
setSearchResults(resultsFromSearch);
}, [items])
```

To me second option is more declarative and more flexible, but it's up to you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as accepted, but there was another thing to change too. Your second option worked, for fetching and showing all data on the first render, first option did not. Another thing was that I had to change array like this: [items, searchTerm, pickedColor]. And not like this: [items, searchResults, colorPickResults]

Comment: sorry, don't follow. where (incorrectly) did you used `[items, searchResults, colorPickResults]` in your code?

Comment: Ah sorry for misleading comment, in code, there are correct values that are: [items, searchTerm, pickedColor]. It was just that while I tried to fix code with information from you I also created another problem for me by replacing array above with: [items, searchResults, colorPickResults]. So finally the correct array to put there so fetching and filtering were working was: [items, searchTerm, pickedColor], and create two useEffect's where one was for fetching with empty array [] at the end.